# Binding from custom window Style into ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I may be going about this the wrong way so if i am let me know.

i'm building a reusable custom window style, where i've recreted the titlebar and everything else already. Now i want to place login data (user name, pic and sign in/out) in the titlebar too.

I've already have all that designed in my `Xaml` and looks great. I also have a `DependecyProperty` where i can set from my window using this style wether i want the login área to show or not through an extension class.

Now i need to create `DependencyProperties` to keep the user data and bind it in the window style definition, however, if i set them in the style and place the properties in the code behind for the titlebar custom control i created (so i could handle drag, etc) then i can't access them from the `viewmodel` to set/get them (or at least i couldn't find a way yet) - but if i don't set them in the style then there won't be a way that i know to set them later)

So how can i either:
1 - access `DependencyProperties` of the view from my `ViewModel` (apart maybe from requiring to pass the `view` to the `viewmodel` - wich seems to defeat the purpose of `MVVM`
2 - bind this `DependencyProperties` of the style from my window's `Xaml` - seems the better option but not sure how to go about it

**EDIT:** it seems some more clarifying is needed:

I'm building library (dll) with a window style (amongst other things) to be reusable in several projects.
As part of the window style above, i have my own custom control handling titlebar stuff (icon, title, system buttons, custom system buttons, window drag, window resize and login área). All is working but the login área.

The login área is basicly:

```
     user name here |  PIC |
   Sign in/out here | HERE |
```

This is overlapped with my custom title bar:

```
   [icon] App Name        [LoginArea][Custom Buttons][System Buttons]
```

My problem is - how to bind the logged in user info to this login area?

Comment: Paragraph #4: Why should you place the properties in the code behind?

Comment: @Bizz - maybe it wasn't clear - i meant the code behind of my titlebar custom control and not the code behind for the app itself. My titlebar custom control is made just with code (1 cs file) with a style beeing applyed to it (style is in a xaml resource dictionary). It is in this style that i set up the "login area" composed of a stackpabel with 2 hyperlink textblocks and a image control. My issue now is how to bind to these 3 controls. One option is to bind them to dependencyproperties in the controls code - but then i wouldn't know how to change the data at runtime.

Comment: option 2 is have the login data in my main viewmodel but then i don't know how to bind it since this is a library to be reuseable and so right now i can't take guesses at a binding path

Comment: From what you said it shouldn't be any problem if you bind normally like Username="{Binding Username}". you just have to set the DataContext of the titlebar correctly. e.g. <my:CustomTitleBar DataContext="{Binding LoginVm}"/>

Comment: @Bizz - true - except that as i mentioned this is to be reusable and i don't have a path to bind to as each app that will use it will have it's own path. I did find a way though - thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution for this. Given my concept i don't have a datacontext path to bind to at library design time. Each app that will use this library will likelly have it's own path - since that data will need to be managed by the app and not the library. I can however have a class already defined in the library for the app to use.

So in my library i have a class for user data with the bare minimum requeired for visualization plus a dictionary for optional use to keep other user data the app may need for it's own purposes:

```
class UserData : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    .... //set private fields

    public string DisplayName {
        get { return ....; }
        set {
            if (.... != value) {
                .... = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    .... Other properties including an all purpose dictionary to keep custom data
}
```

With this in place i can then have in my main window's `ViewModel` an object of type UserData that the app can use to keep user data.

Meanwhile my window style uses my custom titlebar control:

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    .... <!-- other settings -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                .... <!-- other stuff -->
                <controls:TitleBar x:Name="TitleBar" ..... />
                .... <!-- other stuff -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</style>
```

And my custom titlebar's style has my login área, with all controls properly binded according to the class i created for user data:

```
.... <!-- other stuff -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
.... <!-- other stuff -->
```

Back to my main window (that is using my window style that brings in all this) i place the following in the `Loaded` event (this seems the sooner it can be done - i get exceptions if i try this in the constructor)

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var titlebar = (Control)Template.FindName("TitleBar", this);
    titlebar.DataContext = (DataContext as MyMainViewModelType).LoggedUserData;
}
```

With `MyMainViewmodelType` being the class of my main window's `ViewModel`, and `LoggedUserData` a property within that Viewmodel of type UserData (my class from the beginning) with the user data.

The UserData class should instanciate defaults to all properties so that before logging in there's no issues with what is shown

Comment: This solution will definitely work but somehow limited. The MainWindow in which MainWindow_OnLoaded is placed shouldn't necessarily know about inside its style. Which means if you want to add other styles for your window (like a set of themes) you have to go with the same Login TitleBar in all of them.

Comment: @Bizz - not quite - any themes to the window style would only need to use my titlebar control to have all the logic or not use it and create their titlebar from scratch and any themes to my titlebar control could either use my class, in all or partially, for the login bindings, use their own login style/login class and appropriate bindings or have no login at all - it's all decoupled the way i did it

Comment: @Bizz - as for the MainWindow_OnLoaded - yes that's sort of a drawback but i don't see it as problem. All it means is that the view know it has a TitleBar control (i see no issue as a control is a view object) and it knows it must set a datacontext for that control (this i wich could be changed but no way to do it) - your solution makes the View require the ViewModel to own an object of a specific type with a specific name (here i think mine is a bit better - although one could argue negligibly)

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way you can make it work with one small draw back. any view model assigned to this window must contain a Login object.

MainWindow in your main application:

```
<Window Style="{StaticResource myWindow}">
</Window>
```

MainWindow code behind: (this is where the view model is set)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var vm = new MainVm();
    vm.Login = new LoginVm();
    vm.Login.Username = "please enter username";
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

View models: (MainVm contains an instance of LoginVm)

```
public class MainVm : DependencyObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a bindable value that indicates Login
    /// </summary>
    public LoginVm Login
    {
        get { return (LoginVm)GetValue(LoginProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoginProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoginProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Login", typeof(LoginVm), typeof(MainVm), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
public class LoginVm : DependencyObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a bindable value that indicates Username
    /// </summary>
    public string Username
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UsernameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UsernameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UsernameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Username", typeof(string), typeof(LoginVm), 
        new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

TitleBar CustomControl in your library: (a property added)

```
public class TitleBar : Control
{
    static TitleBar()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TitleBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TitleBar)));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a bindable value that indicates Username
    /// </summary>
    public string Username
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UsernameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UsernameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UsernameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Username", typeof(string), typeof(TitleBar), new PropertyMetadata("default"));
}
```

Resource Dictionary in your library: (notice the binding paths)

```
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="myWindow">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ToolBar>
                        <local:TitleBar DataContext="{Binding Login}"/>
                    </ToolBar>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TitleBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TitleBar}">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Username}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If this is what you want then you can add additional properties and commands in the same way. I Hope it's helpful.

Comment: +1 very similar to what i came out with (i was typing my answer when you answered) - the difference is my solution is more general (as i wanted) allowing Windows with no login at all and those with a login to give any property (of the correct type) as the titlebar's datacontext as oposed to requiring a `Login` object specifically

Comment: I agree, both solutions have some drawbacks. The correct way might be to create a custom control equipped with user/pass as dependency props so that they can be set from main app. however in this case it strangely shows a black screen when the custom control is derived from window. I couldn't make it work.

Comment: you mean create a custom window control and then instead of <Window ... have <MyCustomWindow ... in the XAML? I think that may be too much work for what i need and not as flexible but should work - odd the black screen though - something off in your style maybe?

Comment: Yes and it's described here: http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

Comment: It seems using a CustomControl to create a custom window takes more than what I did. so a black screen was all I got!